# How do I change shell prompt permanently?

Tags: linux, shell, prompt

I use `PS=$` to change the shell prompt to `$`, but when I restart the shell, I have to do it again. Is there a way to change the shell prompt permanently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, change the PS1 variable in your `$HOME/.bashrc`.

Comment: Added the the `$HOME` environment variable since @alwbtc might not know where `.bashrc` is. :)

Comment: :) Thanks, I didn't know that indeed.